# CSS Image Slideshow not fitting the screen size

Tags: html, css

When I'm creating an Image slideshow it does not crop the slideshow to the browser size correctly, I need it to have the arrows formatted correctly and the image with padding around the edges still.

I've tried changing some widths and heights to 100% but cannot figure out in what combination if any.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);


.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 690px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
 
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 690px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
 

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 650px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<section class="story-area bg-seller color-white pos-relative">
        <div class="pos-bottom triangle-up"></div>
        <div class="pos-top triangle-bottom"></div>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                        <img class="heading-img" src="images/heading_logo.png" alt="">
                        <h5><b>Check out our</b></h5>
      <h2>Gallery</h2>
                </div>
    <ul class="slides">
     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
       <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-222.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-214.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-262.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-297.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-293.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-084.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-dots">
       <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
       <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
       <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
       <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
       <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
       <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
     </li>
    </ul>

                <h6 class="center-text mt-40 mt-sm-20 mb-30"><a href="#" class="btn-primaryc plr-25"><b>SEE TODAYS MENU</b></a></h6>
        </div><!-- container -->
</section>
```

This should allow me to have a fully working slider with the images fitting the screen accordingly.

Comment: Can you please reduce the code to just what is necessary to reproduce the problem? See the "how to ask" document.

Comment: Also may I suggest using `vh` instead of `%`? As in: `width: 100vw; height: 100vh'. `vh` is view height. While I'm not sure if this will solve your problem with the amount of unnecessary code in your question, it is worth an attempt.

Comment: yes, I've tried that, but i don't know what sizes are the problem. that's all the code for the slider and frankly, it could b any bit of it causing the issue

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: It just breaks it even more by taking it out of the container.

Comment: `padding: 0px`, `margin: 0px`. I'm sure you've already tried this and the standard, I don't really know what the issue is. It would really help if you could reduce the code down to the bare minimum required to produce the problem.

Comment: You should not have nav elements in each slide. There should be one set of navigation arrows which appear above all the slides, not a set of arrows inside of each slide. consider a library like [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) or [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: Try having a look at this [image slide show example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow)

Comment: You have a fixed width on your slides as your slide.. As long this is defined ofcourse it will not go above these sizes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make width `width:100%` to make it full width, Also make body default margin to 0. I have done changes accordingly, please check.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

body{
 margin:0;
}
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 690px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
 
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 690px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
 

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 650px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<section class="story-area bg-seller color-white pos-relative">
        <div class="pos-bottom triangle-up"></div>
        <div class="pos-top triangle-bottom"></div>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                        <img class="heading-img" src="images/heading_logo.png" alt="">
                        <h5><b>Check out our</b></h5>
      <h2>Gallery</h2>
                </div>
    <ul class="slides">
     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
       <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-222.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-214.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-262.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-297.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-293.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
     <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://www.tiggis-ribblevalley.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tiggis-084.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
       <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-dots">
       <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
       <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
       <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
       <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
       <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
       <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
     </li>
    </ul>

                <h6 class="center-text mt-40 mt-sm-20 mb-30"><a href="#" class="btn-primaryc plr-25"><b>SEE TODAYS MENU</b></a></h6>
        </div><!-- container -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

"When I'm creating an Image slideshow it does not crop the slideshow to the browser size correctly"

You have defined dimensions of 1000 x 690 pixels for the component `.slides` and it's children `.slide`. You would have to make these "responsive" by using a non fixed value (for instance 100vw or 100%, depending on your use-case).

Then each `.slide` should be identical size to `.slides` and it should autmatically resize when the viewport changes